# MD5($pwd . $salt) Hashcat Commands

Tags: hashcat

Trying to brute force a basic hash of a plaintext password and a hash... But having difficulty with the hashcat commands.

I'm unsure how to specify what my salt is. I've selected that the -m command is (10) and -a 3 for brute force, but whenever I try to load my hash +  salt I get "Line-length exception"

My command is:
hashcat64.exe -m 10 hash.txt -a 3

Comment: How dows your hash.txt look like?

Answer (score 2):

You "specify" the salt by having the correct format for the hashing algorithm.

For -m 10, or md5($pass.$salt), [see this example is directly from the hashcat website](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes):
`01dfae6e5d4d90d9892622325959afbe:7050461`

Note the colon after the password hash, which separates it from the salt. If your file already looks like this, maybe try adding a new line to the end?